# Which shell command can I use In windows (XP or older) to bring me the print picture dialog?

Tags: python, windows, shell, printing

In Python, if I want to open/launch the default browser using shell, I can import os and execute run "www.google.com". Is there any similar way to open the print pictures dialog for a given image.jpg as if right clicking it and selecting print in the context menu that I can use to call this routine from python???

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `win32api.ShellExecute` with the `"print"` verb. An example: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html

Comment: Printing is a responsibility of a specific program. Whatever the registry says. Invoking the shell is the right way to have the right program attempt to print the file at hand.

Answer (score 2):

At least on my Windows system (Windows 7), there seems to be no trivial way to achieve this. I found that a naive call to ShellExecute appeared to do nothing. Then I tried this:

```
import time, win32api
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", "test.jpg", None, None, 0)
time.sleep(5)
```

With the addition of the call to `sleep()` the dialog appeared, but when the python process terminated, the print dialog closed too.

Since the print dialog runs in-process I don't see an easy wait to wait on it. If it were to run as a separate process then it would be trivial to wait on that process.

I suppose a hacky solution would be to run this through `pythonw` so that no console appeared, and put in a long sleep.  You might end up with some stray Python processes that were aimlessly sleeping, but that might not matter.