# Windows Printer Dialog using python win32 api

Tags: python, winapi, printing, pywin32, pywin

I need the printer dialog(windows default print dialog which appears after ctrl+P) when I shall print a doc using python. How to do it?

Comment: maybe `win32print` can help you here

Answer (score 0):

you might find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253846/which-shell-command-can-i-use-in-windows-xp-or-older-to-bring-me-the-print-pic) and more specifically in this referenced [link](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html).

Short version:

```
win32api.ShellExecute(...)
```